# Finding Area with Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hey everyone, I'm confused with how to solve this question. I understand that Area = 1/2r$^2$ but I'm confused as what the interval would be and whether there would be two different integrals that I must find the difference of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta_1$ denote the value of $\theta$ that solves $8\cos \theta=1$. Then,
$$A_{\text{common between curves}}=\int^{\pi/2}_{\theta_1}(8\cos \theta)^2d\theta+\theta_1$$
Thus,
$$A=16\pi-\left(\int^{\pi/2}_{\theta_1}(8\cos \theta)^2d\theta+\theta_1\right)$$

Comment: I'm confused as to how I find $\theta_1$ I know that the arccos(1/8) = 1.44546 but I'm not sure how I can turn that into pi. Is there a strategy on how to find that or do i just need to understand graphs in terms of polar coordinates?

Comment: @Shenuque $\theta_1=1.44546$ radians, and so you can substitute that in the equations above. To find $\theta_1$, just use a calculator. I don't know of any other method to do this.

Comment: The integral would then give me .0418721 and when you do 16pi - .0418721 you get 50.2445 which seems to be the incorrect answer.

Comment: @Shenuque Did you include $\theta_1$?

Comment: ahhh good catch thank you, Sanath

Comment: @Shenuque Sure!